# Show that it is equal to $\text{Im}f\oplus \ker g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $M$ be a $R$-module.

I want to show that if $f:M\rightarrow N$ and $g:N\rightarrow M$ are $R$-module homomorphisms such that $gf=1_M$ then $N=\text{Im}f\oplus \ker g$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let $g(n)=m$.

Let $n=f(m)+(n-f(m))$.

We have that $f(m)\in \text{Im}f$ and that $g(n-f(m))=g(n)-g(f(m))=g(n)-m=m-n=0$, i.e., $n-f(m)\in \ker g$.

Is this correct?

Now it is left to show that $\text{Im}f\cap \ker g=\{0\}$, or not?

Suppose that $x\in \text{Im}f\cap \ker g=$, which is non-zero.

Then $x\in \text{Im}f$, i.e., there is a $y \in M$ such that $f(y)=x$, and $x\in \ker g$, i.e., $g(x)=0$, or not?

Then we have that $g(f(y))=g(x)\Rightarrow gf(y)=0\Rightarrow y=0$.

Is this correct? How could we continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your attempt is correct; you have nothing more to do.

---

Here's an unabridged version of your proof.

Let $x\in N$; then
$$
x=fg(x)+(x-fg(x))
$$
Note that $fg(x)\in\operatorname{Im}(f)$; moreover $g(x-fg(x))=g(x)-gfg(x)=g(x)-g(x)=0$, therefore $x-fg(x)\in\ker g$.

Hence $N=\operatorname{Im}(f)+\ker g$.

Thus we only have to prove that $\operatorname{Im}(f)\cap\ker g=\{0\}$.

Suppose $x\in\operatorname{Im}(f)\cap\ker g$. Then $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in M$; next $0=g(x)=gf(y)=y$, so $x=0$.

Comment: But at the last part, where we have supposed that $x$ is nonzero, we have concluded that $y=0$, or not? Do we get in that way a contradiction?

Comment: @MaryStar Where did I assume $x\ne0$? I prove that if $x$ is in the intersection, then $x=0$.

Comment: Ah ok... But we have that $y=0$. How do we conclude that $x=0$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar $x=f(y)=f(0)=0$.

Comment: Do we have that $f(0)=0$ because $f$ is a $R$-module homomorphism and so $f(ra)=rf(a)$, for $r=0$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it's a very basic result.